# Table width and height woes for multipage landscape table

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, landscape

I'm writing up my thesis and trying to convert a table to LaTeX (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3523805/table/T1/).  It's rather large so I'm using the lscape and the longtable library.  In addition, some rows have multiple lines so I'm using the pbox library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895780/latex-how-to-code-tables-with-multi-line-cells).

I'm facing two problems.

First deals with columns - despite trying to set `p` widths, I'm not seeing column widths change.

```
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{50pt}|ll|p{40pt}@{}@{}p{100pt}|p{40pt}|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{30pt}|p{50pt}|}
```

The current rendering has lots of extra space between the 40pt and 100pt columns and the last 50pt column is running off the page.

The second problem I have deals with lines that use the pbox hack - boxes that use them are not properly aligned with other cells.

Am I doing this right?  Any ideas?

Full code is below:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{pbox}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{50pt}|ll|p{40pt}@{}@{}p{100pt}|p{40pt}|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{30pt}|p{50pt}|}
    \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
    \hline
     & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Sex} & \textbf{Age of onset (death)} & \textbf{Clinical Presentation} & \textbf{Family Hx} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Biochemical Features}} & \textbf{Gene Candidate(s)} \\
     & & & & & & Tissue(s) & I & II & III & IV & \pbox{30pt}{mtDNA \\ quantity} & \\
     \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
     & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Sex} & \textbf{Age of onset (death)} & \textbf{Clinical Presentation} & \textbf{Family Hx} & \textbf{Tissue(s)} & \textbf{I} & \textbf{II} & \textbf{III} & \textbf{IV} & \pbox{30pt}{mtDNA \\ quantity} & \textbf{Gene Candidate(s)} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    Complex I & P1 & M & $<$1mo & lethal infantile mitochondrial disease &  & fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & *ACAD9 \\
    & P2 & F & $<$1wk (3wk) & hypotonia, lethargy, respiratory distress, metabolic acidosis, FTT &  & fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & nd & *POLG \\
    & P3 & F & $<$1wk (4mo) & severe IUGR, FTT, recurrent episodes of metabolic acidosis &  & skm, fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & NDUFB3 \\
    & P4 & F & in utero (in utero) & multiple pterygium syndrome, severe fetal hydrops, IUGR, terminated at 21w & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$}  &  &  &  & nd & AKR1B15 \\
    & P5 & F & $<$1wk (1yr) & lethargy, tachypnea, organomegaly, renal \& liver failure &  & skm,liv,hea & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & 49\% liv & - \\
    & P6 & M & $<$1wk & bilateral optic nerve hypoplasia, lethargy, FTT &  & skm,liv,fib & $\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P7 & M & $<$6mo (28mo) & cystic leukodystrophy, FTT, severe metabolic acidosis &  & skm,liv,fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P8 & F & $<$3m (8yr) & leukodystrophy, DD, abnormal LFTs, vasculitic rash &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib \\liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ } &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P9 & F & in utero (4d) & leukodystrophy, IUGR, metabolic acidosis, seizures &  & \pbox{20cm}{liv,fib \\ skm} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  &  &  & 460\% liv & - \\
    & P10 & F & $<$1yr (na) & FFT, DD, seizures, hypotonia, prominent extra-axial CSF space &  & skm & $\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\  \hline
    Complex III & P11 & F &$<$1wk & severe global DD, tachypnea, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis, FTT &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm,liv \\ fib} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  & 47\% skm & *BCS1L \\
    & P12 & M &$<$1wk (na) & severe IUGR, lethargy, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis, dysmorphic facies & cons. (1st). & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  & nd & *TYMP, MTCH1, C6orf125 \\
    & P13 & M &$<$6mo & hypotonia, FTT, DD, short stature, rickets, pruritis, dysmorphic facies & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & nd & ACADSB \\
    & P14 & M &$<$1wk (na) & fetal hypokinesia, Pierre Robin sequence, intra-abdominal calcification &  & skm,fib &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & nd & UCP1, MTHFD1L \\
    & P15 & F & in utero (5yr) & ventriculomegaly, apnea, dev.regression, hypotonia, seizures &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  & nd & UQCR10 \\
    & P16 & M &$<$1wk & cardiorespiratory arrest, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis &  & fib &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & nd & - \\ \hline
    Complex IV & P17 & M &$<$1wk & neonatal lactic acidosis, cystic leukodystrophy &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & *COX6B1 \\
    & P18 & M &$<$1wk & hypsarrhythmia, FTT, dystonia, squint &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & $\sim$ &  & $\sim$ & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & nd & *GFM1, ACOX3 \\
    & P19 & F &$<$1mo (12mo) & DD, seizure, hypotonia, doesn’t fix \& follow, cortical atrophy & cons. (1st+1) & fib &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & ACAD8 \\
    & P20 & F &$<$1yr & mild global DD, hypotonia, mild cerebral atrophy & sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & C7orf10, MTERF \\
    & P21 & M & 1mo (7mo) & Leigh syndrome, global DD, FTT, hypotonia, seizures & cons. (2nd) & fib &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & - \\
    & P22 & F & in utero & IUGR, oligohydramnios, severe global DD, seizures, microcephaly, hyperthermia & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm,liv \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & - \\
    & P23 & F &$<$1mo & profound hypotonia, paucity of movement &  & skm &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 37\% skm & - \\
    & P24 & M &$<$1yr & DD, hypotonia, apnea, spastic diplegia, dysmorphic &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 84\% skm & - \\
    & P25 & M &$<$6mo & Leigh-like syndrome, respiratory failure, lactic acidosis, RRF &  & skm &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & - \\ \hline
    Combined OXPHOS deficiencies & P26 & M & 3wk & FTT, metabolic acidosis, hepatomegaly, apnea & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} &  & nd & LYRM4 \\
    & P27 & M &$<$1wk (2mo) & FTT, hypotonia, hypothermia, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, hepatomegaly & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 800\% liv & *TSFM \\
    & P28 & F &$<$1mo (1mo) & FTT, hypertonia, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, respiratory arrest & cons. (1st), sib. & fib & $\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & nd & *TSFM \\
    & P29 & F &$<$1yr & DD, seizures, hypotonia, episodic metabolic acidosis &  & liv & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 167\% liv & *GFM1 \\
    & P30 & M &$<$1mo & FTT, DD, sensorineural deafness, renal failure, dysmorphic & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 42\% skm & - \\
    & P31 & M &$<$1yr & hypertrophic cardiomyopathy &  & \pbox{20cm}{hea \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & C1orf31 \\
    & P32 & M &$<$6mo & gastroesophageal reflux, FFT, hypotonia, respiratory distress, lactic acidosis &  & skm & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & EARS2 \\
    & P33 & M &$<$1yr (20mo) & FTT, dev.regression, microcephaly &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} & 290\% skm & ALDH1B1, mtDNA del. \\
    & P34 & F &$<$1wk (4mo) & FTT, cardiac arrest, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl}  & 88\% skm & - \\
    & P35 & F &$<$1wk (10d) & metabolic acidosis, cardiac failure, hemorrhagic brain infarct &  & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 190\% liv & - \\
    & P36 & M &$<$1yr & sudden-onset encephalopathy with seizures after URTI &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ $\sim$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 92\% skm & - \\
    & P37 & F &$<$1yr & DD, ptosis, microcephaly, GI dysmotility &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 53\% skm & - \\
    & P38 & F &$<$1yr & leukodystrophy, speech delay, dysaesthesia in hands, dev.regression &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ nl} &  \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 112\% skm & - \\
    & P39 & M &$<$2yr & Leigh syndrome, global DD, deterioration after URTI &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} & nd & - \\ \hline
    mtDNA dep. & P40 & F & in utero (stillborn) & stillborn with hypotonia and multiple fractures &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl}& \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 8\% skm & *AARS2 \\
    & P41 & F &$<$1yr (18y) & cardioskeletal myopathy, cataracts, FTT, fatigue &  & skm & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 4\% skm & AGK \\
    & P42 & F &$<$1wk (4d) & marked respiratory distress, pulmonary hypertension, cataracts & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl}& \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{13\% skm \\ 88\% liv} & AGK \\ \hline\hline
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Actually running into a third issue now - I'm trying to insert this code into a [template](https://github.com/aleifer/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation) and the formatting has gone completely haywire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had more columns specified than you were using so the last one wasn't being used. The "continued" multicolumn was wider than the columns that it was spanning so forcing the fourth column to be over wide, I just made it span another column. It's best not to put `@{}` between internal coluns otherwise teh text in adjacemt columns will touch. `center` has no effect on longtable so I deleted it.

I added some colour so I could see which column is which.

I left in the `\parbox` commands although probably you don't need them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}

    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \small
\noindent X\dotfill X

    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{50pt}|
>{\columncolor{red}}l
l|
>{\columncolor{yellow}\raggedright}p{70pt}
>{\columncolor{blue}\raggedright}p{70pt}|
p{40pt}|c|c|
>{\columncolor{yellow}}c|
c|c|c|
>{\columncolor{red}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{60pt}|
%%%%>{\columncolor{yellow}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{100pt}|
}
    \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
    \hline
     & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Sex} & \textbf{Age of onset (death)} & \textbf{Clinical Presentation} & \textbf{Family Hx} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Biochemical Features}} & \textbf{Gene Candidate(s)} \\
     & & & & & & Tissue(s) & I & II & III & IV & \pbox{30pt}{mtDNA \\ quantity} & \\
     \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
     & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Sex} & \textbf{Age of onset (death)} & \textbf{Clinical Presentation} & \textbf{Family Hx} & \textbf{Tissue(s)} & \textbf{I} & \textbf{II} & \textbf{III} & \textbf{IV} & \pbox{30pt}{mtDNA \\ quantity} & \textbf{Gene Candidate(s)} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    Complex I & P1 & M & $<$1mo & lethal infantile mitochondrial disease &  & fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & *ACAD9 \\
    & P2 & F & $<$1wk (3wk) & hypotonia, lethargy, respiratory distress, metabolic acidosis, FTT &  & fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & nd & *POLG \\
    & P3 & F & $<$1wk (4mo) & severe IUGR, FTT, recurrent episodes of metabolic acidosis &  & skm, fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & NDUFB3 \\
    & P4 & F & in utero (in utero) & multiple pterygium syndrome, severe fetal hydrops, IUGR, terminated at 21w & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$}  &  &  &  & nd & AKR1B15 \\
    & P5 & F & $<$1wk (1yr) & lethargy, tachypnea, organomegaly, renal \& liver failure &  & skm,liv,hea & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & 49\% liv & - \\
    & P6 & M & $<$1wk & bilateral optic nerve hypoplasia, lethargy, FTT &  & skm,liv,fib & $\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P7 & M & $<$6mo (28mo) & cystic leukodystrophy, FTT, severe metabolic acidosis &  & skm,liv,fib & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P8 & F & $<$3m (8yr) & leukodystrophy, DD, abnormal LFTs, vasculitic rash &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib \\liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ } &  &  &  & nd & - \\
    & P9 & F & in utero (4d) & leukodystrophy, IUGR, metabolic acidosis, seizures &  & \pbox{20cm}{liv,fib \\ skm} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  &  &  & 460\% liv & - \\
    & P10 & F & $<$1yr (na) & FFT, DD, seizures, hypotonia, prominent extra-axial CSF space &  & skm & $\downarrow$ &  &  &  & nd & - \\  \hline
    Complex III & P11 & F &$<$1wk & severe global DD, tachypnea, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis, FTT &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm,liv \\ fib} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  & 47\% skm & *BCS1L \\
    & P12 & M &$<$1wk (na) & severe IUGR, lethargy, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis, dysmorphic facies & cons. (1st). & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  & nd & *TYMP, MTCH1, C6orf125 \\
    & P13 & M &$<$6mo & hypotonia, FTT, DD, short stature, rickets, pruritis, dysmorphic facies & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & nd & ACADSB \\
    & P14 & M &$<$1wk (na) & fetal hypokinesia, Pierre Robin sequence, intra-abdominal calcification &  & skm,fib &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & nd & UCP1, MTHFD1L \\
    & P15 & F & in utero (5yr) & ventriculomegaly, apnea, dev.regression, hypotonia, seizures &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} &  & nd & UQCR10 \\
    & P16 & M &$<$1wk & cardiorespiratory arrest, metabolic acidosis, renal tubular acidosis &  & fib &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & nd & - \\ \hline
    Complex IV & P17 & M &$<$1wk & neonatal lactic acidosis, cystic leukodystrophy &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & *COX6B1 \\
    & P18 & M &$<$1wk & hypsarrhythmia, FTT, dystonia, squint &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & $\sim$ &  & $\sim$ & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & nd & *GFM1, ACOX3 \\
    & P19 & F &$<$1mo (12mo) & DD, seizure, hypotonia, doesn’t fix \& follow, cortical atrophy & cons. (1st+1) & fib &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & ACAD8 \\
    & P20 & F &$<$1yr & mild global DD, hypotonia, mild cerebral atrophy & sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & C7orf10, MTERF \\
    & P21 & M & 1mo (7mo) & Leigh syndrome, global DD, FTT, hypotonia, seizures & cons. (2nd) & fib &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & - \\
    & P22 & F & in utero & IUGR, oligohydramnios, severe global DD, seizures, microcephaly, hyperthermia & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm,liv \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & - \\
    & P23 & F &$<$1mo & profound hypotonia, paucity of movement &  & skm &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 37\% skm & - \\
    & P24 & M &$<$1yr & DD, hypotonia, apnea, spastic diplegia, dysmorphic &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} &  &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 84\% skm & - \\
    & P25 & M &$<$6mo & Leigh-like syndrome, respiratory failure, lactic acidosis, RRF &  & skm &  &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & - \\ \hline
    Combined OXPHOS deficiencies & P26 & M & 3wk & FTT, metabolic acidosis, hepatomegaly, apnea & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl} &  & nd & LYRM4 \\
    & P27 & M &$<$1wk (2mo) & FTT, hypotonia, hypothermia, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, hepatomegaly & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 800\% liv & *TSFM \\
    & P28 & F &$<$1mo (1mo) & FTT, hypertonia, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, respiratory arrest & cons. (1st), sib. & fib & $\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & nd & *TSFM \\
    & P29 & F &$<$1yr & DD, seizures, hypotonia, episodic metabolic acidosis &  & liv & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 167\% liv & *GFM1 \\
    & P30 & M &$<$1mo & FTT, DD, sensorineural deafness, renal failure, dysmorphic & cons. (1st), sib. & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 42\% skm & - \\
    & P31 & M &$<$1yr & hypertrophic cardiomyopathy &  & \pbox{20cm}{hea \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & nd & C1orf31 \\
    & P32 & M &$<$6mo & gastroesophageal reflux, FFT, hypotonia, respiratory distress, lactic acidosis &  & skm & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & nd & EARS2 \\
    & P33 & M &$<$1yr (20mo) & FTT, dev.regression, microcephaly &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow\downarrow$} & 290\% skm & ALDH1B1, mtDNA del. \\
    & P34 & F &$<$1wk (4mo) & FTT, cardiac arrest, hypertrophic cardiomyopathy &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$ \\ nl}  & 88\% skm & - \\
    & P35 & F &$<$1wk (10d) & metabolic acidosis, cardiac failure, hemorrhagic brain infarct &  & \pbox{20cm}{liv \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 190\% liv & - \\
    & P36 & M &$<$1yr & sudden-onset encephalopathy with seizures after URTI &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ $\sim$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & 92\% skm & - \\
    & P37 & F &$<$1yr & DD, ptosis, microcephaly, GI dysmotility &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 53\% skm & - \\
    & P38 & F &$<$1yr & leukodystrophy, speech delay, dysaesthesia in hands, dev.regression &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\sim$ \\ nl} &  \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 112\% skm & - \\
    & P39 & M &$<$2yr & Leigh syndrome, global DD, deterioration after URTI &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} &  & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\downarrow$} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow$ \\ $\sim$} & nd & - \\ \hline
    mtDNA dep. & P40 & F & in utero (stillborn) & stillborn with hypotonia and multiple fractures &  & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ fib} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl}& \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & 8\% skm & *AARS2 \\
    & P41 & F &$<$1yr (18y) & cardioskeletal myopathy, cataracts, FTT, fatigue &  & skm & $\downarrow\downarrow$ &  & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & $\downarrow\downarrow$ & 4\% skm & AGK \\
    & P42 & F &$<$1wk (4d) & marked respiratory distress, pulmonary hypertension, cataracts & cons. (1st) & \pbox{20cm}{skm \\ liv} & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & & \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl}& \pbox{20cm}{$\downarrow\downarrow$ \\ nl} & \pbox{20cm}{13\% skm \\ 88\% liv} & AGK \\ \hline\hline
    \end{longtable}

    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - that was a dumb mistake.  I'm still running into a problem when I copy the table into the [thesis document](https://github.com/aleifer/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation/blob/master/harvard-thesis.cls) it becomes way too wide.  It appears that `p` columns are taking up the full page width.  Changing the # of `pts` or units doesn't do anything and - if I change the first column to an `l`, a lot  more of the table shows.  How can I begin to debug this?

Comment: sounds odd, usual way start with a document that's wrong and remove stuff (especially if you can remove local class:-) while keeping the problem and when it's as small as you can get post a question.... that thesis class is xetex specific by the look of it and based on book, so start with book and then add the packages the thesis class uses until something breaks.